# Is there any efficiency issue in duplicated importing in vue.js

Tags: performance, vue.js, import

I do refactoring some vue code And find duplication like below;

```
- main.ts
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vuew';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

I know that if main.ts do 'import bootstrap-vue' then other vue file use bootstrap component without importing.
But my co-worker do this meaningless imporing on every vue component.

So i Wonder that is this duplication has any critical efficiency issue?
If yes, it related to velocity of rendering?

Comment: Is it `bootstrap-vue` and not `bootstrap-vuew`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. `bootstrap-vue` is right..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imports themselves aren't a problem. A module is evaluated and included into a bundle only once. It's discarded in production build if imported values aren't used in modules that import them.

It's `Vue.use` that makes it different. Imported plugin won't be discarded because it's used. A plugin can do side effects that should be applied only once and should have a safeguard against multiple installation. The plugin in question [has such safeguard](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/v2.21.2/src/utils/plugins.js#L35), so this introduces no problems except several bytes of unnecessary code per module.

The necessity of this is doubtful. Vue plugins affect global application behaviour. `Vue.use` needs to be used only once per plugin, this is commonly done in entry point, but can be done in feature modules as well, the latter can specify their own plugin dependencies for decoupling purposes. It doesn't make sense to use `Vue.use` in each module where library components are used. Instead they can import components per need basis, this allows to not include the whole library, considering that there's no plugin installation anywhere in the application.

So it's either installing a plugin once or several times globally per application or feature module:

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

Or using a subset of library locally as many times as needed:

```
import { DropdownPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue';
Vue.use(DropdownPlugin)
```

And/or importing all used components locally as many times as needed:

```
import { BDropdown, BDropdownItem, ... } from 'bootstrap-vue';
export default {
  components: {
    BDropdown, BDropdownItem, ...
  }
}
```

It always depends on a library if it's supposed to be used one way or another.

Comment: I got it perfectly. Thanks much. And if i may do, i want to ask one more question.

Importing all of plugin used in project on 'main.ts' by 'Vue.use(~)' is terribly wrong?

Comment: No, it's a common practice. Importing components like shown in snippets 2 and 3 is a way to optimize the bundle, it especially makes sense when it's obvious that the project doesn't use the whole library.

Answer (score 0):

Importing a library in global "main.ts" enough to use in any component throughout the application. But importing multiple times in all components can cause large size build file. So, it's better to use only one import of the library in "main.ts".

Comment: *But importing multiple times in all components can cause large size build file.* - no, it can't, unless the project is configured the wrong way. Naturally, such import will end up in some general chunk (`common` in Vue CLI setup)